# multiple progress bar on single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I am trying to put multiple progress bar with different values on a single page. 
Value will come from database by php.

Below is the html code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="progressbar.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="progressbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skins/tiny-green/progressbar.css">

</head>
<body>


    <div id="progressBar" class="tiny-green"><div></div></div>


    <script>
        progressBar(105, $('#progressBar'));
        progressBar(15, $('#progressBar'));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the **progressbar.js**

```
function progressBar(percent, $element) {
    if(percent > 100){
        percent = 100
    }

    var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(percent + "%&nbsp;");
}
```

It is working fine for single progressbar.
Can you please advise me how to show multiple progressbar on single page.

Comment: Why can't you just add another progress bar with a different ID, and call it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prograssBar function creates a new progress bar and attach it to existing element.
You need multiple elements of you want multiple progress bars.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="progressbar.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="progressbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skins/tiny-green/progressbar.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="progressBar1" class="tiny-green"><div></div></div>
    <div id="progressBar2" class="tiny-green"><div></div></div>

    <script>
        progressBar(105, $('#progressBar1'));
        progressBar(15, $('#progressBar2'));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of options

### Option 1

You can have multiple elements with incrementing IDs like this

```
<div id="progressBar1" class="tiny-green"><div></div></div>
<div id="progressBar2" class="tiny-green"><div></div></div>
<div id="progressBar3" class="tiny-green"><div></div></div>
```

And initiate like this

```
progressBar(105, $('#progressBar1'));
progressBar(15, $('#progressBar2'));
progressBar(105, $('#progressBar3'));
```

### Option 2

Or you can use class like this

```
<div class="progressbar tiny-green"><div></div></div>
<div class="progressbar tiny-green"><div></div></div>
<div class="progressbar tiny-green"><div></div></div>
```

And pass an array like this

```
progressBar([105,34,243], $('.progressBar'));
```

And modify your progressBar method to something like this

```
function progressBar(percents, $elements) {
  $elements.each(function(index, el) {
      var percent = percents[index];
      if (percent > 100) {
        percent = 100;
      }
      var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
      $(el).find('div').animate({
        width: progressBarWidth
      }, 500).html(percent + "%&nbsp;");
    }
  });
}
```